# How do I delete the Kind entity, itself in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know all my data are cleared out by default every time I restart the development server on Google App Engine, but I need to know that when I start deploying, I can programmatically delete not just the entities of all the Kinds, but also the Kind entities, themselves, as I change them during development/deployment cycles.

Looking at similar questions, I came up with this attempt:

```
from model import *
from google.appengine.ext.db import *
from google.appengine.ext.db.metadata import *

for i in Kind.all():
    if i.kind_name == 'Person':
        i.delete() # Try one way
        db.delete(i) # Try another way
        print "Yes"
        break
```

...but this prints "Yes" every time, indicating that the 'Person' kind is not being deleted.  Is this just an artifact of the development server, or can you never delete Kind entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete the Kind returned by a metadata query. The App Engine Datastore has a dynamic schema that will automatically adapt when you delete the last entity of a kind. It is possible that the dev appserver has some lag here -- or possibly you are mistaken that the Datastore is deleted each time, since this not supposed to happen. What makes you think that it does?

PS. Don't use import * so much, it makes your code harder to read and might cause bugs due to name conflicts...

Comment: Well, it's not lag, because I run that code manually in the interactive console (which is also why I take the import * shortcut), and it doesn't matter how long I wait.

Comment: I also have found that the dev_appserver.py, when using the datastore_file_stub (the default), never writes the pickle file.  That's why it's cleared every time.

Comment: FYI, I just discovered that the issue of the dev appserver not writing the file is due to a bug in the Launcher UI. When it stops the dev appserver it sends it a hard kill. Try running the dev appserver from the command line and stopping it with ^C, then it will save. To delete all entities of a kind, do a keys only query and call db.delete() on the list of keys, in batches of 100 or so.

Comment: @tamboril The point is, though, that the kind entity is just metadata - it's not like a table definition. It will go away when the metadata is updated.